# Azure AD DS -- Create Failover Cluster Instance (Access Denied)

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

please I have deployed Azure Active Directory Domain Services Azure AD DS in my environment and added 2 VMs into this domain. When I tried to create WINDOWS failover Cluster , it failed with below error

Create computer object ggg on domain controller \aaaa.bbbb.onmicrosoft.com in organizational unit OU=AADDC Computers,DC=bbbb,DC=onmicrosoft,DC=com. Access is denied.

I've owner permissions on Subsction and hence on Azure AD DS.

Please how can I create cluster or prestage CNO in Azure AD DS .

Please I tried all permissions combinations but all failed.tried with powershell with Admin too

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the error ***"Create computer object ggg on domain controller \aaaa.bbbb.onmicrosoft. com in organizational unit OU=AADDC Computers,DC=bbbb,DC=onmicrosoft,DC=com. Access is denied."***

*I suggest you try following the below steps:*

> Make sure to grant the user permissions while creating cluster like
> below:

***Active directory users and computers - > View -> Advanced features -> Right click on CNO -> Select properties -> Security tab -> Add -> Select Users, computers or groups -> click on user account -> select Ok -> Allow check box of the permissions -> Select ok.***

Check whether you have granted the permissions to the OU, by following this [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/failover-clustering/prestage-cluster-adds#step-3-grant-the-cno-permissions-to-the-ou-or-prestage-vcos-for-clustered-roles).

For more in detail, please refer this link : [Prestage cluster computer objects in Active Directory Domain Services | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/failover-clustering/prestage-cluster-adds#step-3-grant-the-cno-permissions-to-the-ou-or-prestage-vcos-for-clustered-roles).

Comment: Thank you @Rukmini. Plz it is Azure AD DS. I tried to check it through installation of Active directory features on another server but couldnt find way to prestage CNO

Comment: Please can anyone shed light on it. Moreover Can we create CNO,VCO clustering objects in Azure AD DS.?